# Macro or Shortcut to toggle

Tags: windows, windows-10, macros

[After reading this StackOverflow question](https://superuser.com/questions/426293/keyboard-macro-to-change-default-audio-device) I wanted to know if it was possible to have a keyboard shortcut that does some specific sound settings.

My system is Windows 10.

Whenever I want to start playing PC games through a headset (and record multiple audio tracks), I use this sound setup thanks to VB-Audio Cable:
[image]
However, part of the process of loading up any game (after plugging in my USB headset) is to first go into the VB-Audio Virtual Cable Output in the Listen tab and change between my speaker system and headphones (see Speakers & Headset Earphone):
[image]
and then I have to toggle off-and-on the Listen to this Device in the VB-Audio Cable A properties:
[image]

Yes, I know this is a bit of a thing. It's just how my setup currently works. Is there a way I can get a macro to do this automatically so it's just a matter of double-clicking on a desktop shortcut?

1. Swap the VB Virtual Audio Cable device between Speakers and Headset
2. Toggle OFF and then ON, the Listen to this Device flag, in the VB-Audio Cable A,

**Note** - I have to keep my playback settings like this; VB Virtual Audio Cable set as Default Device:
[image]

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you may not know and it may be an even better solution for you... In Windows 10, if you click on the speaker icon, when multiple devices are present, you can click on the top bar and switch to a different audio device.  The same functionality is also in the GameBar (accessible by pressing WIN+G) which can be accessed even while you are in game.

Comment: I have to keep my Playback devices as this. I tried your comment but it doesn't affect my settings.[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuLfI.png