# Why keyboard shortcut to switch between monitors doesn't work with Volume2 app?

Tags: windows-10

Question to those using this great app.

I defined a keyboard shortcut to switch to a secondary monitor (as displayed on attached screenshot), but it doesn't work.

**When I press F1 (the bind key), nothing happens.**

[image]

```
Action: Run application
Keys combination: F1
Parameter: c:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /external
```

My sysinfo:

```
Windows version: Windows 10 Pro (Version: 22H2, Build: 19045.3803)
Volume² version: Version 1.1.8.465 (16.09.2023)
```

**I don't know why it doesn't work. Please advice.**

**One weird thing that I noticed:** DisplaySwitch.exe is exactly where it supposed to be.
However, when I use Volume2 UI and click on that folder icon next to Parameter field to select DisplaySwitch.exe, I don't see it. I see in in File Explorer, but not through Volume2 UI.

Thank you.